# Fix broken DNSSEC

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec

I have transferred a .com domain from Namecheap to EuroDNS.

Since that day I have the problem that the domain does not resolve from all DNS servers, e.g.:

```
$ host -a flibsy.com 8.8.8.8
Trying "flibsy.com"
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

Host flibsy.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
Received 28 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53 in 77 ms
```

Someone suggested me that I have "broken DNSSEC", as can be seen here:

http://dnsviz.net/d/lxsky.flibsy.com/dnssec/ and http://dnsviz.net/d/flibsy.com/dnssec/

EuroDNS told me they do not support DNSSEC.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DNS service provider doesn't support DNSSEC, you have exactly two options:

1. Switch to a provider that does support DNSSEC.
2. Disable DNSSEC by contacting your *registrar*.

   It seems that EuroDNS is both your dns provider and your registrar. The deactivation process is probably just like their [activation](http://help.eurodns.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2439032-how-do-i-activate-dnssec-for-my-domain-) process, but instead of adding a key you'll remove it.

Comment: I had no way to remove the DS entry myself, but EuroDNS did it a few minutes after I requested it in a ticket.